# How do I truncate a string at the last letter before the first occurrence of a digit?

Tags: python, string, parsing, indexing

I am trying to find things in a string - all of them are before a number, for example:

```
"Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2"
```

This is an index from a file such that `file[2] = "Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2"`

how can I write code that will select only the text and leave out the numbers and any white space before those numbers (as below)?

```
"Diablo Lord Of Destruction"
```

I understand you can easily do this by doing something like this:

```
contents = file[2]
print contents[0:-2]
```

Since the values will be changing, I need a more robust solution that can handle different sized numbers and different lengths of white space.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's difficult to see what's being asked.

Comment: Have you heard about regular expression?

Comment: 1. I have a list which I am selecting an index from. 2. The index from the file contains numbers which I want to remove. 3. The index is always in the same format "blah blah blah more blah sometimes #.#.#" 4. I want to take that index, in general, and be able to remove just the numbers in whichever method that works.

Comment: @AlejandroPiad Heard?, yes. Actually used, applied, and studied them? Nope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and the [sub()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) method:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
>   string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it
>   are processed.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[0-9.]*', '', 'Diablo Lord of Destruction 9.2')[:-1]
'Diablo Lord of Destruction'
>>> re.sub('[\d.]*', '', 'Diablo Lord of Destruction 9.2')[:-1]
'Diablo Lord of Destruction'
```

The code above will find all number occurrences, [0-9.] or [\d.], and replace them with ''.  In addition, it trims the last character, which was a space.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly, and easy to understand as well, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Larson A note for the future: I think you should try to learn about a regular expressions, since they are really valuable tools for many problems, the simpler of which is this one. So, now that you have your answer, go into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression and try to get used to them. You'll find it very useful.

Answer (score 7):

This removes any digits and full stops from your string:

```
import re
>>> filtered = re.sub('[0-9.]*','',"Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2  111" )
>>> filtered
'Diablo Lord Of Destruction   '
>>> filtered.strip()           # you might want to get rid of the trailing space too!
'Diablo Lord Of Destruction'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'll always have a space before the number, you can [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string. For example:

```
contents = file[2].split() # Gives a list split by whitespace
contents.pop() # Dump the number
finalStr = ' '.join(contents)
```

From running a test:

```
>>> test = "Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2"
>>> contents = test.split()
>>> contents
['Diablo', 'Lord', 'Of', 'Destruction', '9.2']
>>> contents.pop()
'9.2'
>>> finalStr = ' '.join(contents)
>>> finalStr
'Diablo Lord Of Destruction
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect job for regular expressions. Specifically, you can use the following code to extract all of the text that precedes a number:

```
import re
s = "Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2"
print 'Text: ', re.match('([^0-9]+)',s).group(1)
```

Regular expressions are a bit of a pain to master but well worth the effort.

Comment: `re.match('([^0-9]+)',"two * 2 = four").group(1)`

Comment: @Rakis Can you explain how the ^ works here, I've never used that before.

Comment: @Maria Zverina Op stated that the string will always be in the same format "blah blah blah more blah sometimes #.#.#"

Comment: @Larson It's in the re module's documentation (highly recommended read) but when used as the first character within [], it means match everything *except* what's in the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
filter(lambda ch: not ch.isdigit(), "Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2")
```

Comment: Though, this will leave the dot `.`.

Answer (score 1):

To get all text until the first number is encountered:

```
import re

s = "Diablo Lord Of Destruction 9.2"
print(re.match(r'\D*', s).group(0))
```